# Declaration of n number variable at runtime

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a graph in crystal report which displays values of 15 categories.
But I want to make it user define graph.

User of my application choose no. of category he wants. as per this condition i want to change my graph.

I am able to display all category in a graph.

Now I want to pass multiple category to a stored procedure and retrieve result and show it into graph.

I am sending Categories in string variable with comma

```
string abc = 'a,b,c'
```

Now I want to separate a b c and compare it with one column. and get the data n display the graph of category a, b, c

Answer (score 0):

create a Dynamic parameter in crystal reports to list all those categories. Enable multiple values, so the user can select the ones he/she wants to show on the report and under record selection formula you will write `{your field} in ?your parameter`.